# Heuristics for mixed integer linear and nonlinear programs

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, solver, nonlinear-programming, heuristics

What are some primal heuristics that mixed-integer linear and nonlinear program solvers use to quickly obtain a reasonably good feasible solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a question, for which google "primal heuristics integer program solver" may give a better answer than I can give myself, but: One of the "definitive" references is [this dissertation](http://www.zib.de/berthold/Berthold2014.pdf) by Timo Berthold.